# Why is my texture not showing up?

Tags: texturing, objects

I'm currently trying to upload an image to a plane mesh and it only shows in the "texture" preview and not in world.

Example:

[image]

https://gyazo.com/8134a4ba8c440bdbd07dd83bd3e598bd

I've tried everything as in other tutorials and none of them either relate to how simple my problem is or have nothing to do with it.

My viewport shading is set as texture as well, and I've also tried unwrapping it(another tutorial).

Things you should know:
I'm using Cycles
Yes the image is a .jpeg
I'm also decently new to Blender

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Could you upload a blend here?](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) There are a number of things that could be wrong as far as I see it.

Comment: Hi. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ if you want to share .blend files. Files on other file sharing services tend to "vanish" over time thus making your question and possible answers less useful.